# I have a addressList part inside my elasticsearch record, but i am unable to create a query to get the value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

Below is the part of address field inside my record

```
 "addressList" : [
            {
              "city" : "Göteborg",
              "country" : "",
              "fullAddress" : "Lilla Bommen 5A, 411 04 Göteborg, Sverige",
              "location" : {
                "longitudeLatitude" : {
                  "lat" : 57.7123,
                  "lon" : 11.9677
                }
              },
```

and the mapping I have for this part is as follows

```
"addressList" : {
          "properties" : {
            "city" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "country" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "fullAddress" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "location" : {
              "properties" : {
                "longitudeLatitude" : {
                  "properties" : {
                    "lat" : {
                      "type" : "float"
                    },
                    "lon" : {
                      "type" : "float"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "prov" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
```

i want to get the record based on latitude longitude and distance, at this point i really dont want to edit my mappings as well, I am struggling for weeks to get a query to fetch records based on lat lon

Comment: One thing is sure `longitudeLatitude` should be a `geo_point` instead of two floats. Floats will never get your where you expect with geo queries

Comment: @Code Noob can you give 1 example of what type of query and search result you are expecting to get ?